# Extend child div to one side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something with my website that I'm having a very hard time wording into a Google search. I have a container div sitting inside of a section element that expands across the entire width of the page. I want the container width to extend out to the left side, and the right side to never extend beyond a specific point.

Here's my existing code:

html

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
   </div>
</section>
```

css

```
section{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This results in the `container` div being centered in relation to the `section` element. As the width of the browser changes size, the `container`'s left and right bounds stay the same.

[image]

Now I want to extend the left side of the `container` while the right side stays the same. How can I do that?

[image]

The key part of this is having the right side of the `container` stay where is it **relative to the center of the section**, so even if the width of the browser changes, that right side doesn't move.

The reason I'm doing this is so I can put a background image on `container` and have it expand to reach the left side of the page.

EDIT:
I also must be able to put elements inside the container and have them reach the right edge, so padding won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly this might work:

```
.container{
    width: 1200px;
    padding-right: calc(50% - 600px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked. When I tested it, I forgot to put a space on both sides of the - sign so it didnt work at first. I have never heard of calc before. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I forgot to mention that I want to also put other elements inside the container div. the padding prevents any other elements from aligning to that right edge... :/

Comment: You can position them with `position: absolute`

Comment: The container has `display: flex` since I use flexbox for the elements in there. `position: absolute` works for the div going on the right, but the other flexbox elements seem to ignore it.

Comment: Got it, just used another div to serve as the flexbox parent. Thanks for your time!